# Symfony4 different security configurations for different environments

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-security

I've seen instructions all over for doing this in symfony 3.4 but I can't figure out how to do this in Symfony 4. I have a custom environment and when a developer sets APP_ENV to that environment I want a different security.yaml to be used. Say for example I created a configuration environment 'local', when I have config/packages/local/security.yaml and APP_ENV=local, my app still defaults to config/packages/security.yaml. I want config/packages/security.yaml to be completely ignored in favor of config/packages/local/security.yaml.

Here is my `prod/security.yaml`:

```
security:
    providers:
        shibboleth:
            id: App\Security\User\ShibbolethUserProvider
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            stateless: true
            anonymous: ~
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - app.shibboleth_authenticator

            logout:
                path: /logout
                success_handler: app.shibboleth_authenticator

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/result, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

And here is my `local/security.yaml`:

```
security:
    providers:
        in_memory: { memory: ~ }
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: ~
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Symfony4 you split your configuration in environment folders. What you want to do is probably the following:

```
.
└── config
    └── packages
        ├── dev
        ├── local
        │   └── security.yaml
        ├── prod
        │   └── security.yaml
        └── tests
```

It works this way thanks to this line inside your `Kernel.php` https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/34fc4212d838ac6c49a2b9892e2aa1d926149192/symfony/framework-bundle/3.3/src/Kernel.php#L48

```
$loader->load($confDir.'/{packages}/'.$this->environment.'/**/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, 'glob');
```

Comment: This is actually what I have and it still doesn't work. It just grabs the 'security.yaml' file that comes first in the directory tree and ignores any after, regardless of APP_ENV.

Comment: I updated the post to include my config files and their locaction

Comment: Actually this does work, it was a caching issue. Thanks! One thing that doesn't seem to work though is if I want to limit `config/packages/local/security.yaml` to work for APP_ENV=local but then have one other security.yaml file for all other environments. I tried `config/security.yaml` but then `config/packages/local/security.yaml` is disabled for local env as well. According to this https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/configuration_organization.html, I would of thought this to work.

Comment: Actually looking at the code you posted I see why that doesn't work. They should a `config/services_dev.yaml` naming for other configs. I don't really see any other option other than to copy security.yaml to all environment directories...